# Failed to Retrieve Application JMX Service URL in Spring Boot IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-jmx

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am encountering an issue when running my Spring Boot application in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. Upon starting the application, I consistently receive a notification indicating that the **`"Failed to retrieve application JMX service URL."`**

**Environment**

Operating System: macOS Ventura 13.5

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Version: IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2 (Ultimate Edition)

Spring Boot Version: 3.1.2

Java Version: 17

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAYJk.png)

I am seeking assistance in resolving this problem.

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ IDEA, open Spring Boot's `Run/Debug Configurations` and add the following line to the `VM Options`:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```